# Is there a benefit to validate the signature in an OAuth Authorization Code Flow?

Tags: oauth

We're utilising OAuth's [Authorization Code Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow) to authorize the user for an internal action within the application, as opposed to handing off the access token to a separate API.

Under normal circumstances the API recipient would validate the signing of the access token to confirm the token came from the OAuth server expected.

However in this case, as the access token is being using internally, does validating the signing make sense?  Specifically given that the request to get signing keys will go to exactly the same host as the application retrieved the token from, it seems to me that it doesn't improve security materially.

The other claims (audience, expiry, etc) obviously still require validation.

Comment: How is access token token sent to your service? In the form of signed cookies or in the request header? If the cookies are signed, you don't have to verify the token.